# Why do I get this message whenever I try to access a website on Tor?

Tags: help

[image]
Whenever I try to access any Tor website with .onion, it brings up this message

Comment: Do you use Tor Browser or a plain Firefox?

Comment: Tor Browser, not FF

Comment: Do you get the same thing for the example hidden service, http://duskgytldkxiuqc6.onion/ ?

Answer (score -1):

First, take a look at your proxy settings - you **must** resolve hostnames via proxy, *not by regular DNS queries*. Second, take a look at your Tor logs: is it "100% bootstrapped" when you're trying to use it to reach an onion website?

Comment: The user already stated they are using Tor Browser. They will not be resolving by regular DNS queries.

Comment: Because I have seen an attempt from ISP to hijack this kind of situation

Comment: Again, they will not be using regular DNS so that's entirely irrelevant.